# How to accept 9 first characters in excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am trying to get this sort of result, where I check on sheet1 if the first three numbers on column A are found anywhere in the sheet2's column A. If the numbers are found then on column B excel prints Yes and if it is not found excel prints No:

Sheet 1

```
    A         B  
    =12300    Yes
    =56700    Yes
    =89200    No
```

Sheet 2

```
    A
    =12345
    =56789
    =44498
```

The formula that I have at the moment on sheet1 col B is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1;Sheet2!A:A));"Yes";"No")
```

How to add the possibility to check that it takes into consideration only the 3 first characters in both sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use a `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1,3)=LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,3))),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. If I have =12477 in sheet2 and =12500 on sheet 1 I still get Yes. I have to use ";" instead of ",". I don´t know if it makes any difference in this case. I am not very familiar with excel.

Comment: It makes a huge difference @waspe :). Exchange the comma's with a semi-colon.

Comment: Agreed with @JvdV, depending on your local settings you might need to replace all `,` with `;`. If it still does not work please paste a screenshot and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes I switched all your commas to semi-colons in my formula. But it still does not work in my case.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot please? As you can see it works on my side -> [link](https://i.imgur.com/kzOMILw.png)

Comment: Your values actually have a `=` in front, so change the 3 in the `LEFT` function to a 4 if you want to include the equal operator @waspe

Comment: Well now I just feel kind of stupid :D . Thanks! One more thing: There´s quite a lot of data and I should check the whole col in sheet 2. Is this the right way: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1;4)=LEFT(Sheet2!A:A;4)));"Yes";"No")`

Comment: @waspe, try and avoid whole column references. Whether you have a lot of data or not, it's probably not over a million rows long. In other words, referencing a whole column using array formulas will slow down your workbook significantly.

Comment: That is correct, however, as @JvdV already indicated in his post, we strongly recommend limiting the number of rows where the search is performed. The last row in Excel is `1048576` so, unless you have that much data, restrict your range like `LEFT(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1000;4)`

Answer (score 2):

You can ***initially*** try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),LEFT(Sheet2!A1:A3,3),0)),"YES","NO")
```

And make sure to enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Notice the reference of the *used range*, with array formulas you would want to try and *avoid whole column references* because of performance issues. In this specific case we could make it dynamic through:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),LEFT(Sheet2!A1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)),3),0)),"YES","NO")
```

Now we got a dynamic formula, we might as well try to avoid the use of having to enter it as an array formula. We could implement an `INDEX` to take care of that issue:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),INDEX(LEFT(Sheet2!A1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)),3),),0)),"YES","NO")
```

So there we have it; a dynamic array formula that avoids having to enter as such =)

---

If your values actually start with a `=` then you should reference the first 4 characters of the value with `LEFT`. And to also take into consideration your parameters are seperated through semi-colon, the final formula would look like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1;4);INDEX(LEFT(Sheet2!A1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A;COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A));4););0));"YES";"NO")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many perfect answers to this question, but it can also be done by adding a wildcard to the end of your string instead of the actual value:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Yes","No")
```

As @JvdV pointed out, this doesn't work properly for numeric values, only for text. As per his suggestion:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",INDEX(TEXT(Sheet1!A:A,"0"),),0)),"Yes","No")
```

Would do to omit this issue. Also please read the comments for his suggestion not to use a whole column as reference.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work as intended Plutian. Have you tried it and got the results you wanted?

Comment: I have, several times. It takes the first three characters from the cell and either does or does not find a match in the range. If this won't work, can you elaborate? I'd love to learn what I've done wrong.

Comment: To me, the following changes would make it work: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",TEXT(Sheet1!A:A,"0"),0)),"Yes","No")` entered as array formula. You'll need to compare text values against a text value, otherwise there would never be a matched value. Interesting approach though with the wildcard. Note that whole column references will slow this thing down significantly =)

Comment: @JvdV I see, I've tried to play about with mine as well, and came to the same conclusion, that it doesn't work properly for numeric values. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll use this knowledge for later, and for now I'll update my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Just one more thing, as per my last comment; just check the difference in calculation time using a whole column reference and just the three cells. That would tell you that whole column references on array formulas are not good for performance. Either way, in your current solution: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",INDEX(TEXT(Sheet1!A:A,"0"),),0)),"Yes","No")` would prevent having to enter the formula through ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: If my initial answer had worked, referring to a whole column wouldn't be much of an issue. However to account for text and numeric values like you did it definitely will. Thank you for suggesting these edits, since I'm here to learn as much as anyone. You've definitely given me some insight and things to play about with.

Comment: No worries Plutian. I've noticed you pick up on things quickly. And the wildcard suggestion is a valid one, just a bit difficult on numeric values, but if there really are equal signs in front of OP's data, it might become a very neat approach (since his data should be text). Therefor +. OT: I specifically liked the trick with `INDEX` to avoid the use of ctrl+shift+enter. You'll notice it can come in handy more often =)

Comment: Yes I picked up on that one, very neat trick when array formulas are almost unavoidable. Definitely will play about with that and add it to my concept files. +1 for you as well for teaching me something new.

Comment: BTW, if OP's values have an equal sign (as per the other answer's comments), then your initial answer is very usefull > `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A1;4)&"*";Sheet2!A:A;0));"YES";"NO")`

Comment: @JvdV True, but I find it is always best to account for all situations like you did, to avoid a long debugging process and many head scratches or possible downvotes in the case of non compliant data.